# How to setup jquery autocomplete in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I created the basic "rails blog app" to understand how to properly implement jquery autocomplete. I installed [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) according to its documentation.

Currently my app looks like:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
end
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find params[:id]
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new article_params
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit :title, :text
    end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160607060132) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

I have two problems now:

1. When I now go the my articles index.html.erb I get the following error message:

[image]

2. I started coding just few months ago. Following the documentation of [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) leaves me totally lost on the question how to implement autocomplete for my app. I basically just want a view with a search field that searches the title of my articles.

So my questions now are:

1. Why am I getting the error message above?

> **UPDATE** The following application.js resolved question #1.
>
> ```
> //= require turbolinks  
> //= require_tree .
> //= require jquery
> //= require jquery_ujs
> //= require autocomplete-rails
> ```

2. How should my code look like for a simple search field that searches the title of my articles?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is you **bundle install** successfully done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 4, First install `bundle install`, then just use `autocomplete-rails` as in following:

```
//= require turbolinks  
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

Comment: Any ideas about question #2? (Sorry for my noob questions but I just started coding and try to understand how everything works)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have run bundle install 
(`bundle show jquery-rails` to verify that gem was successfully installed.)

After that put `//= require jquery.turbolinks` under `//= require jquery`

```
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require autocomplete-rails
```